# Use regex to parse parameter line with whitespace in parameters but without quotes

Tags: python, regex

It is possible to parse such a line with regex:

```
name=This is tricky pos=81 key=4565 count=1 pass=a_23 find=2
```

into groups

```
('name=This is tricky', 'pos=81'...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your text with `\w+=` that will returns the following result :

```
>>> re.split(r'(\w+=)',s)
['', 'name=', 'This is tricky ', 'pos=', '81 ', 'key=', '4565 ', 'count=', '1 ', 'pass=', 'a_23 ', 'find=', '2']
```

then use `zip` within a list comprehension the concatenate the relevant elements :

```
>>> sp=re.split(r'(\w+=)',s)[1:]
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(sp[0::2],sp[1::2])]
['name=This is tricky ', 'pos=81 ', 'key=4565 ', 'count=1 ', 'pass=a_23 ', 'find=2']
```